# Swift Navigation Bar button Fix button order on device language change

Tags: swift

In swift 4, I am using NavigationBar , in left and right side, i have 2 buttons on each side. , eg, in left side , the outer button is back, then phone call next to it (custom view).
When device language changes, button orders changes, button order changes, so that the PhoneCall Button is to the outer side, then back button next to it.

I have tried Semantic = .forceRighttoleft into the storyboard for the Navigationbar, but did not work. I have also set it programmatically at ViewDidLoad or ViewwillAppear. , but did not work

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.semanticContentAttribute = .forceLeftToRight
```

I need to set it device language independent.

**Below "Back Arrow" is to left, while Basket to right to it. This is correct.**

[image]

**By changing device language , back button is set right to basket button , which is not correct.**

[image]

Any idea.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Changing `semanticContentAttribute` only won't work because based on [Apple's Doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiappearance):

> iOS applies appearance changes when a view enters a window, it doesn’t change the appearance of a view that’s already in a window. To change the appearance of a view that’s currently in a window, remove the view from the view hierarchy and then put it back.

You need to reload the **NavigationController** only after that it will work.

Comment: the issue is in the left side of the the navigationbar, it has 2 buttons  (back & phone call). the issue is that the back must be always to the left, while phone call right to it. Is device language changed, i get phone call button to the left, and phone call button to its right.

Comment: I have added screenshots with the issue. Hope this may make question clear. Thanks.